# Render Multiple grids on the same page with different dataset

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I have two datagrids on the same page. The goal is to have each datagrid make an API call with different parameters and render data, so they function individually.

I am able to have the grids make different API calls and get data. But, I am facing an issue setting the data individually to those grids.

I created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/server-driven-datagrid-starter-nqmwuk), demonstrating the issue.

**app.component.ts**

```
refresh(state: ClrDatagridStateInterface, postId) {
      this.loading=true;
      const filters: { [prop: string]: any[] } = {};
      if (state.filters) {
        for (const filter of state.filters) {
          const { property, value } = <{ property: string; value: string }>filter;
          filters[property] = [value];
        }
      }
      if (state.page != undefined && state.page != undefined)
      {
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading = true;
        this.getData(postId, state.page.from, state.page.size );
        });
      }
  }

    getData(postId:string, page: number, size:number  ) {
    this.userAccounts$ = this.informationService.GetUserAccounts(postId);
      this.userAccounts$
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) || null
            this.loading = false
        }
        );
    }
```

I am generating the grids in a for loop using an array of Post Ids.

```
posts:any = ["1","4"];
```

Each grid is supposed to make an API call with that postId,

```
Ex: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1
Ex: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=4
```

to get `postId` and `email` and display it in the grid. Each grid needs to function individually, whether it is sorting or filtering or paging.

The `getData` function is setting API data globally for use for both grids. How can I can set it for the grids individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always settting `this.users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) || null` in your subscription, and always looping over `users`. So basically you're not creating a different property to hold the data.

Generally, I would argue against this approach. What I would do is encapsulate the whole datagrid one time as a component with an input to accept the configuration data (seems like `postId`). Then reuse the component twice to get your duplicate datagrids that are individually encapsulated. Otherwise, you've got a lot of logic bleeding between both datagrids and it could be hard to manage.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That worked much better.